# VisualStudio2019 でコードを切り貼りすると、必要以上にコードが戻る

Tags: visual-studio

VisualStudio2019 Community, C#

ボタン等のイベントをGUIで作成し、作成された場所がコード末尾なので、別の場所に移動しようとイベントのコードを切り取りし、貼り付けすると、コードが必要以上に過去のものになっています。
そのイベントと全く関係ない箇所もです。

また、イベント以外のコードの切り取り時も発生するかもしれません。

怖くて再現してみることができないのですが、過去5回以上は発生しています。
最近はコピーし、貼り付け、最後に不必要なコードを消去しています。
そうすれば発生しないようです。

設定項目で、コードが勝手に戻ってしまうことをなくすことはできるでしょうか？
また、どういうときにコードが勝手に戻ってしまうのか、そのルールを知りたいです。

なお、GUIでフォーム名を変えると、「コードをすべて新しいフォーム名に変えますか？」等というダイアログが表示されることは知っています。
しかし今回の現象では、そのダイアログは表示されず、コードが勝手に戻ってしまいます。

語彙力がなく、わかりづらくてすみません。

Comment: 関係無いかもしれませんが、例えばこんな機能[【Windows 10最新機能】クリップボードが大幅に進化！ 履歴＆同期機能の使い方](https://dekiru.net/article/17279/) を有効にしていたり、それに類するツールをインストール・使用していたりとかありませんか？ あるいは[コードのリファクタリング](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/refactoring-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)に関連する機能を使う操作になっていたり、同様の機能を持つ拡張機能パッケージをインストールしていてて常時有効になっているとか？

Comment: kunif様、ありがとうございます。クリップボード履歴＆同期は無効でした。教えていただいた他の項目についてはもう少し調べてみます。

Comment: 分からないようでしたら、たとえ長くてまとまりが無かったとしても、発生している具体的な状況と場面毎の対象テキストとかスクリーンショットで詳細を追記すると、場合によっては直ぐに助言や回答が付くかもしれません。

Comment: 切り取り、貼り付けはどのように行っていますか？CTRL＋C、CTRL+V等のショートカットでしょうか？それともメニューの編集から切り取り、貼り付けでしょうか？

Comment: 池田茂樹様、CTRL＋C、CTRL+V等のショートカットを使用しています。

Comment: kunif様、再度いろいろ試して再現してご報告いたします。

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studioは昔からクリップボード履歴機能が独自に搭載されています。
ctrl+shift押しながらvを押すたびに張り付ける内容を切り替えられます。
操作ミスで上記を行った可能性などはありませんでしょうか？

Comment: takemori_kondo様、ctrl+shift押しながらvを押した覚えはないのですが、再度いろいろ試して再現してご報告いたします。